# NTFS treating files as temporary without T attribute, and not replicating over DFS

Tags: ntfs, dfs, dfs-r

I have found a folder of files that are failing to replicate between my DFS servers, and I can't find any documented reason why. Here are some examples:

```
FileName                               Attributes
package_2019-08-09-11-07.zip.filepart  A
package_2019-07-08-13-39.zip.filepart  A
package_2019-07-03-08-34.zip.filepart  A
cifs39e2                               HA
cifse038                               HA
cifsb676                               HA
```

- the hidden `cifsxxxx` files are the same size as the package files (~200mb), but are from different dates. The name may be a cifs-related bug? These aren't my files.
- The Replicated Folder has the default file filter, which won't include these:

  ```
  ~*, *.bak, *.tmp
  ```
- They don't have the `Temporary` attribute. `fsutil` shows only `0x20` or `0x22`
- They aren't listed in the DFS replication health report or logs.

These files seem to be created by uploading a file through WinSCP > SFTP > Linux Server > mounted SMB share, without having enough permission to rename the temporary `.filepart` file. I'm not worried about the permissions, but why are these files treated as temporary?. It has to be some part of the metadata, because if I copy one of the files and rename it, DFS will notice and replicate the new file.

Even weirder: The files aren't visible to even the file owner from the linux server when mounted using a cifs mount, but show up using smbclient as the same user.

I want to find out why these files aren't replicating so that I can search the server for other inconsistencies.